# How to include a file in Maven like you can include in PHP

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a Maven J2EE project. 
Since Maven and PHP do not go together very well, I need some other method that functions like the PHP include function.

I need to include my header and footer file in my HTML files. What can I use for this?

Comment: Maven is not intended to use related with Maven...What is your problem and how is J2EE related to PHP ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to inject my footer and header into my HTML page. With PHP you can use an include tag, what would I use for Maven?